# Bootstrap 3 accordion scroll to top when open inside a div overflow-y

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a div container with accordion bootstrap 3 inside.

```
<div id="cont-accordion" style="height: 300px;overflow-y:scroll;">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      <!-- first panel -->
      <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading"> 
              <span class="strong">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"
                    href="#collapseOne" id="predict">
                    Gettysburg <span class="caret"></span>
                  </a>
              </span>
          </div>
       </div>
      <!-- second panel -->
</div>
</div>


jQuery("#accordion").on("shown.bs.collapse", function () {
    var myEl = jQuery(this).find('.collapse.in');
    jQuery('#cont-accordion').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery(myEl).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

When I open the panel, the panel is placed on top, but if I open another panel, this is not positioned at the top.

It only works if i close before the panel.
How can I fix it?

example http://jsfiddle.net/s88x9dtk/

Answer (score 0):

For doing something like that, use the returned event to retrieve the trigger element:

```
$('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (event) {
    var $el = $('[href="#' + $(event.target).attr('id') + '"]');

    $('#cont-accordion').animate({
        scrollTop: $el.offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on("shown.bs.collapse", ".panel-collapse, a[data-toggle='tab']", function () {
      var selected = $(this);
      $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: selected.offset().top
      }, 1000);
});
```